# Why is there no error when you input letters more than malloc size?

Tags: c, malloc, overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  char * chr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
  
  chr = "apple";
  printf("%s", chr);
  
  return 0;

}
```

Hello.
I have a question about malloc.
I made only int sized byte (1byte) with malloc.
And I input oversized letter "apple" (6byte)
I thought the ouput would be like "A" or Null.
But the output was "apple".
How could this possible?

Comment: Please write question as question, not as comment. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Also note that typically you are allocating only 1 byte and `"apple"` is 6 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for editing. I'm not used to this website so I made some mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory malloc assign is not assigned the same way as the memory assigned when declaring a variable or an array.

Malloc (and its derrivates) assign memory in the Heap while declaring a string or an int assign memory in the stack.

```c
char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (elem + 1)); // Here malloc is called, memory is assined in the heap

ptr = "hello world"; // allocates a new space in the stach where the string hello world is stored
```

Basicaly here you are not filling the allocated space of memory with `apple`. You are delacring a new one that contain `apple`.

If you're new to C programming i advise you to learn how to use pointer and arrays before using malloc (try to reproduce strlen, puts or other simple functions like these)

### The next part is only here if you want to roughly understand how it works

#### What's the difference ?

The difference is, your stack memory change while your program process
When your main function is load, it load it variables in the stack. Then when you call an other function such as f1, f1 and it variable will also be load in the stack

Let's take the following code :

```
int f1() {
    int var4 = 0;
    // step 2 and 5
    return (0);
}

char *f2() {
    int var5 = 0;
    int var6 = 0;
    char *f2_ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); // we will ignore this for the first part
    // step 4
    f1()
    // step 6
    return (ptr);
}

int main(void) {
    int var1 = 0;
    int var2 = 0;
    int var3 = 0;
    // step 1
    f1();
    // step 3
    char *main_ptr = f2()
    // step 7
    free(ptr)
    // step 8 (only for Stack + Heap part)    
    return (0);
}
```

There is the shema of your memory step by step

#### Stack Only

step 1 main and our variables has been load

```
main
   var1
   var2
   var3
```

step 2 we've entered in f1, main and our main's variables are still here but now we also have f1 and f1 variable

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
    f1
        var4
```

step 3 we've left f1 so it has been unloaded. main and our main variables are still loaded

```
main
   var1
   var2
   var3
```

step 4 just like in step 2 we've entered in a function (f2), main and our main's variables remains and we load f2 and f2 variables

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
    f2
        var5
        var6
```

step 5 Once again we've entered in f1. f1 and its variable are loaded at the bottom of your stack

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
    f2
        var5
        var6
        f1
            var4
```

step 6 we leave f1, f1 and its variable are unload

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
    f2
        var5
        var6
```

step 7 we leave f2, f2 and its variable are unload

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
```

As you can see, the more we progress in the program the lower in the stack we go.
when we hit a return statement, we go back up in the stack.

#### Stack + Heap

When you use malloc, the allocated space of memory return is not stored in the stack. This allow you to have a memory segment which is not unloaded when you leave the function. This allow you to make dynamic memory allocation and a lot of other stuffs.

Here is the same step by step example with malloc :

steps 1, 2 and 3 are basicly the same as the first part

```
main
   var1
   var2
   var3
```

step 4 this time we use malloc and a new memory segment is allocated away from the stack. its adress is store in f2_ptr

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
    main_ptr
    f2
        var5
        var6
        f2_ptr


malloc_memory_segment
```

step 5 as you can see the memory segment created by malloc remain at the bottom of the memory

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
    main_ptr
    f2
        var5
        var6
        f2_ptr
        f1
            var4

malloc_memory_segment
```

step 6 we leave f1, f1 and its variable are unload

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
    main_ptr
    f2
        var5
        var6
        f2_ptr


malloc_memory_segment
```

step 7 we leave f2, f2 and its variables are unload but not the malloc allocated segment

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
    main_ptr

malloc_memory_segment
```

step 8 we free main_ptr which delete the malloc_memory_segment

```
main
    var1
    var2
    var3
    main_ptr
```

Hope this was clear enough and it helps you understand how your program works

Good luck and keep learning

Answer (score 2):

```
chr = "apple";
```

overwrites the pointer stored in `chr` itself. After that, the string `"apple"` allocated in somewhere when the probram is loaded is used instead of the buffer allocated via `malloc()`. This operation is safe with just leaking a small chunk of memory.

To invoke dangerous *undefined behavior* by doing out-of-range write, you can use [`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) like this:

```
strcpy(chr, "apple");
```

Comment: Worth adding that it does not guarantee the segmentation fault.

Comment: I just tried but the result was same as "apple". Is this normal?

Comment: @Pepper this may be the case, but it is undefined behavior ("UB"). You are writing those bytes into memory that is not initialized, or may contain other data. It *might* work, but you shouldn't allow this type of situation to happen.

Comment: You can use a `really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really` long string, then it is almost sure it will crash.

Comment: @Devolus Surprisingly 50,000-character string coundl't cause crash [in this test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ykuf8QEQToyBfBVI).

Comment: @MikeCAT, really? Well, it's UB, so anything can happen. :)